# Bug fixing for my damage per second function

Tags: php, jquery

I've created a working damage per second loop although it has a few bugs that need to be worked out.

1. i'd like the 'target has been destroyed' message to be displayed instantly, not 1.2 seconds after the current hitpoints reach 0.
2. the major bug is that if you click the attack button multiple times, it will initiate the setInterval multiple times and the damage will be inflicted every 1.2 seconds for every time you clicked it, so it can execute multiple times.
3. The initial attack should happen instantly.

Any thoughts or ideas? I have tried the using a do while loop but i couldn't get that code to work at all. I've only had success with the setInterval function.

I have a working script on my website and i'll post the code here as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dmg = 60;
var curr_hp = 1200;
var tot_hp = 1200; 
$('#attk_spd').html('1.2 seconds');
$('#dmg').html('60');   $('#curr_hp').html('1200');
$('#tot_hp').html('1200');
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $('#attk').html('You are currently attacking your target.');
            setInterval(
                function () {
                    if (curr_hp > 0) {
                        curr_hp = curr_hp - dmg;
                        $('#curr_hp').html(curr_hp);
                    } else { $('#attk').html('Your target has been destroyed.');
                    }

                },
            1200);
        })

});
```

And here's the current working version in action:
http://www.evenstar-online.com/Jquery_snippets/dpsloop.php

Comment: learn how to use `clearInterval` before setting a new one

Comment: @charlietfl Well the thing is i only want it to happen once. If the user clicks the attack button again, nothing should happen. Will the clearInterval button remove future instances of the function once it's started?

Comment: if you declare the interval as variable you can check if it exists or not already then

Comment: @charlietfl yes! You're exactly right. I'm shaking out the dust this week. I've written things like this many times over in php. I don't know why i didn't think of this. I'm still fairly new to the jquery syntax. That should fix my 2nd problem. Still clueless on the 1st and 3rd, but those would more or less be fine tuning luxuries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, so you can control precisely whether to attack again.  Then you can just call the function once and the first attack happens immediately.  This is a little weird to explain; follow the code below  :)

Also:

- Taking care to indent your code correctly makes it much easier to follow at a glance  :)
- Don't use `$.html` unless you're actually assigning HTML!  Get in the habit of using `$.text` instead, or you'll end up trying to stick an angle bracket somewhere and have no idea why all the text disappeared.

I ended up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dmg = 60;
    var curr_hp = 1200;
    var tot_hp = 1200;
    $('#attk_spd').text('1.2 seconds');
    $('#dmg').text('60');
    $('#curr_hp').text('1200');
    $('#tot_hp').text('1200');

    var attack_timer;
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        if (attack_timer) {
            // We're already waiting for the next attack, so do nothing
            return;
        }

        $('#attk').text('You are currently attacking your target.');

        var attack_once = function() {
            // Always attack immediately
            curr_hp -= dmg;
            $('#curr_hp').text(curr_hp);

            // Only schedule another attack if the target is still alive
            if (curr_hp > 0) {
                attack_timer = setTimeout(attack_once, 1200);
            }
            else {
                $('#attk').text('Your target has been destroyed.');
            }
        };
        attack_once();
    })
});
```

Comment: ,That works beautifully. I had rewrote my original code and got a very nice working version of it, but this one you wrote allows for the instant attack. Should i choose to create a retreat button i will have to come up with some way to people can't abuse spamming retreat/attack constantly for instant attacks. Perhaps a cooldown greying out the attack button for 1.2 sec once retreat is hit would be appropriate. That'll come later though haha. THanks!